# Avoiding a BEGIN TRANSACTION error on a read-only Sybase connection

Tags: python-2.7, sybase, pyodbc

I want to use python for a 32-bit odbc connection to a read-only db.
I've installed

```
C:\py_comp>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Downloading pyodbc-4.0.19-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl (50kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 1.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.19
```

and opened a read only connection

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};port=1234;server=11.222.333.444;CHARSET=iso_1;db=my_db;readonly=True')
```

and all the above is working fine but when I try to do a select

```
cursor.execute("SELECT something FROM atable")
```

I get an error because it issues a `begin transaction` but it shouldn't do that.

```
pyodbc.Error: ('ZZZZZ', u"[ZZZZZ] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Attempt to BEGIN TRANSACTION in database 'my_db' failed because database is READ ONLY.\n (3906) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: You could try `conn.autocommit = True` immediately after opening the connection.

Comment: @GordThompson I'm happy to accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specifies that, by default, connections should be opened with "autocommit" off so operations on the database are performed within a transaction that must be explicitly committed (or rolled back). This can result in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` being sent to the database before each batch of `Cursor#execute` calls, and that can cause problems with operations that cannot be performed within a transaction (e.g., some DDL statements).

pyodbc allows us to enable "autocommit" on a connection, either by adding it as an argument to the `connect` call

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
```

or by enabling it after the connection is made

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.autocommit = True
```

That can avoid such problems by suppressing the automatic `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before executing an SQL command.